# About C++ copy (value1 = value2)

Tags: c++

I code in AS3 (An OO Javascript) and I'm learning C++.

It seems that in C++ if you do `instance1 = instance2` you are duplicating `instance1` and naming the copy `instance2`. Not like AS3 where only "Strings" and numbers gets duplicated like that, and other types gets "referenced" so both points to the same object (like C++ pointers).

So my question is:

Suppose I have the source code of "Battlefield 4" (Or any hardware hungry game) and I'm running an instance of the main class of the game like this: `BattleField4 gameInstance = new BattleField4()` and after 5 minutes of the game running the code does this: `BattleField4 gameCopy = gameInstance`.

Does that mean a "total copy" of the game progress and graphics loaded in memory?

If the game loaded 10Gb of memory with it's graphics into the RAM, then 20GB will be loaded after `gameCopy = gameInstance`?

Thanks for your help and I hope my english was clear.

Comment: Well, `BattleField4 gameInstance = new BattleField4();` wouldn't even be legal in C++.  The left side is an object, and the right side is a pointer.  Until we know which type your variable has, we can't answer the copying question.

Comment: If "AS3" means "ActionScript 3" (aka: Flash), then it's *not* similar to Java or C#. It's similar to JavaScript. Indeed, the rest of your question really shows this off.

Comment: Also, no `instance1 = instance2;` does not duplicate `instance1` into `instance2`.  It's the exact opposite.

Comment: Um, the title appears to have nothing to do with the question. The question is too hypothetical to have an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not realy sure if AS3 is similar to Java or C#, and I was confused about what "reference" means in C++, so I've edited the question and title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I self-answer my question:

Every property of the duplicating object gets copied. And yes, that can be a performance problem. That is why people use pointers.
When using the "=" operator, C++ makes a "Shallow Copy" of the object (by default). It is possible to define a copy constructor to change this and for example create a class with a "Deep Copy" mode.

Searching for what is "Shallow Copy" gives me the information I wanted about how C++ object copy works.

This comparition between "Shallow Copy" against "Deep Copy" it's very informative:

> For an object that contains pointers to other objects, a shallow copy copies only the pointers and not the objects to which they point. The result is two objects that point to the same contained object. A deep copy copies the pointers and the objects they point to, as well as any pointers or objects contained within that object, and so on.
>   Avoid performing a deep copy if a shallow copy is all you require.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, if you have some object `obj` of type `Type`, and you perform:

```
obj = newObj;
```

Where `newObj` is also an object of type `Type`, this will invoke `Type`'s copy constructor. Will that perform a "total copy"?

It depends on how `Type` implements the copy constructor. See, in C++, types are allowed to *choose* what happens when a copy is created. Sometimes, it's just copying internal data. Sometimes, you have to instantiate new objects within the type, so that larger objects internally held by pointers can be properly copied.

Sometimes, we say that the `Type` in question has "reference semantics". This means that by "copying" `Type` objects, what you get is two separate `Type` objects that internally refer to the same data. That is, they both *reference* the same stuff. That's perfectly valid and is used in a number of utility C++ classes.

And sometimes, we flat-out *forbid copying altogether*. This is usually done for objects that aren't appropriate for reference semantics and that copying them would be too burdensome. If a game were to have one huge, monolithic object that represented the game, it would be either non-copyable, or its copy constructor would be completely broken and non-functional (game developers are notoriously lazy about these things).

Answer (score 3):

Programmers don't do that. There's no single giant class containing absolutely everything, and if there were, you wouldn't make copies of it. You'd pass around pointers or references to it. That said, if you did have a crazy huge object, and you did

```
CrazyHuge crazy_huge_object_2 = crazy_huge_object;
```

you would (probably, depending on the copy semantics) have two crazy huge objects, and you would be spending twice your original crazy huge amount of memory.

Comment: That depends on whether the object holds its internal members by value, by unique pointer (and does a deep copy), or by shared pointer (and does a shallow copy).

Comment: Singletons? What do singletons have to do with any of this?

Answer (score 0):

None of your examples show use of references. In C++, value semantics are the default. Think of it like a `struct` in C# or Java.

If you want reference semantics, use pointers or references.

Comment: This seems like more of a comment.

Comment: @NicolBolas: How so? I answered the question asked.

Comment: His question is about how things get copied. While the *title* talks about references, the actual question text does not. As you point out, he doesn't actually use any references.

Comment: @NicolBolas: The "None of your examples use references" comment is a comment. The "value semantics are the default" is the answer to the question.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Then the answer is poor for not explaining what "value semantics" means to someone who's only programming experience is *JavaScript* (he claims that ActionScript 3 is "Similar to Java and C#", but that's errant nonsense. It's a JavaScript dialect).

Answer (score 0):

By default C++ will pass by value, unless it is a vanilla array, which is passed as pointer. This is not like most languages, where only primitives are passed by value and all user objects are passed by reference automatically.

That being said - for example Qt containers don't really copy the actual container, unless you try to modify it, which is called "copy or write" with implicit sharing for reading.

As of your case - if the `BattleField4` class offers a "deep copy" constructor or assignment operator, then that would be possible, but I doubt anyone in their right mind would design a game class like that and with such size.

The game hierarchy still exists, but it won't be confined within a single class instance, it will be a part of a polymorphic hierarchy. That means it will lend particularly well to recursive tree traversal with any method that is present in the hierarchy base class and implemented for each specific object. Such an operation most likely won't occur in RAM memory, but will save the hierarchy to disk - this is how saving and loading game progress works - the entire state of all game objects is serialized to disk to save, and de-serialized to restore. Naturally, the same technique can be used to what you ask for, but it doesn't sound like a smart thing to do. And yes, in the case of a deep copy, it will take up double the memory. You will have two separate trees if objects to which you can make changes without affecting the other.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment in C++ for any sophisticated type is user-defined.  Scalar and simple aggregate assignments are by value, but once an object starts acquiring relationships with peers and dependents you'll have told C++ exactly what parts need real duplication and what other effects the duplication will have.  Your game's top-level inventory of media objects will almost certainly be a simple reference copy.